# How to find out when an audio disc (CD) has been written/burned?

Tags: audio, compact-disc, date, forensics

Is there a way/tool to determine the date and time when an audio disc (CD) has been written/burned?

I am aware of [How to find out when a disc (DVD) has been written/burned?](https://superuser.com/a/559089/116475) but the accepted solution doesn't work with audio discs as the latter don't have a file system:

[What format are audio CD files in? 
An explanation of the CDA and CD-DA format](http://www.wizbit.net/cd-dvd_production_faqs_what_format_are_audio_CD_files.htm)

> The [audio CD format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Book_%28audio_CD_standard%29) is typically referred to as a CDA file (.cda). In
>   truth there are no such things as CDA files as they are just created
>   by the operating system to show representations of the audio tracks on
>   a CD.

Hence:

[image]

instead of

[image]

if there were some file system.

So, any idea how to find out when an audio disc (CD) has been written/burned?

---

In reply to user Ramhound's comment, having no file system doesn't prevent CDA from having metadata. See [Compact Disc subcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcode).

Comment: If there is no file system the. What you want isn't possible since there isn't a way to store it

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't prevent CDA from having metadata. See [Compact Disc subcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcode).